# Xcode don't believe, think that I assign property with value of wrong type wrong type

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I created entity Car by `CoreData framework` in my IOS application.
I wrote definition of of my class car in file `Car+CoreDataClass.swift`
Then I wrote properties in extension for this class in file `Car+CoreDataProperties.swift`Property "lastStarted" of type `NSDate` is one of them.
But when tried set new value for property lastStarted of object of `class Car`, Xcode said that this property is type Date not NSDate.
I don't understand why does he think, that lastStarted is Date type, because it was declared as NSDate in `Car+CoreDataProperties.swift`.

//Code From extension

```
extension Car {

@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Car> {
    return NSFetchRequest<Car>(entityName: "Car");
}

@NSManaged public var imageData: NSData?
@NSManaged public var lastStarted: NSDate?
@NSManaged public var mark: String?
@NSManaged public var model: String?
@NSManaged public var myChoice: NSNumber?
@NSManaged public var rating: NSNumber?
@NSManaged public var timesDriven: NSNumber?
@NSManaged public var tintColor: NSObject?
}
```

//Assigning values

```
        car.mark = carDictionary["mark"] as? String
        car.model = carDictionary["model"] as? String
        car.myChoice = carDictionary["myChoice"] as? NSNumber
        car.rating = carDictionary["rating"] as? NSNumber
        car.timesDriven = carDictionary["timesDriven"] as? NSNumber
        car.lastStarted = carDictionary["lastStarted"] as? NSDate //here Xcode says
```

"Cannot assign value of type 'NSDate?' to type 'Date?'"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using xcode 10 with swift 5 then it should be `Date` not `NSDate` .

> You should not create the `Car+CoreDataClass.swift` yourself, you can get xcode to generate them for you